# grouping two numpy ndarrays in specific ranges of one and calculating the mean and distribution of the other in that range

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I'm not sure if I'm asking the question the right way, but consider two ndarrays `x` and `y`:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1000
T = 1.0 / 800.0
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
y = np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * x) + 0.5 * np.sin(3 * 2.0 * np.pi * x) \
    + 0.1 * np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, N)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

now consider `x_2` as

```
M = 10
x_2 = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N//M)
```

kind of grouping `x` into ranges with length of `M`. Now I want to have `y_m` and `y_v` in the below pseudocode:

```
y_m = average of `y`es for x_2_(i-1) < x < x_2_(i)
y_v = variance of `y`es for x_2_(i-1) < x < x_2_(i)
```

for `i` in the range of `0 < i < N / M`. Sure I could define some for-loops but considering that my dataset is huge I'm looking for a more vectorized way using numpy functionalities. Also please consider that the actual ndarrays I have are not sorted.

**P.S.** I was asked to implement the way I know :

```py
M = 10
x_2 = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), N//M)

y_m = np.zeros(N // M - 1)
y_v = np.zeros(N // M - 1)
for ii in range(N // M - 1):
    y_m[ii] = y[((x_2[ii] <= x) & (x < x_2[ii+1]))].mean()
    y_v[ii] = np.var(y[((x_2[ii] <= x) & (x < x_2[ii+1]))])

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x_2[:-1], y_m)
plt.show()
```

**P.S.2.** One idea could be to sort the zipped `(x, y)` according to `x` and then reshape the ndarray and then calculate the mean and variance of the specific axis.

Comment: Could you write out the for loops so we can see exactly what you're trying to achieve? I'm not sure I understand the pseudo code. If I do, for instance: `y_m = y[(x > x_2[i-1]) & (x < x_2[i])].mean()` then you only need one outer loop, but I'm not sure this is what you're after?

Comment: Careful with `x_2 = np.linspace(0.0, N*T/M, N/M)`. You won't consider the whole range of x, but only `1/M` of its total width.

Comment: @ajrwhite added my own implementation

Answer (score 0):

So I got to implement the idea I proposed in **P.S.2.** in the original post, using numpy's `reshape` function:

```py
MM = 10
x_2 = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), N // MM)

z = y[(N % MM):].reshape(((N - (N % MM)) // MM, MM))
y_m = z.mean(axis=1)
y_v = z.var(axis=1)

plt.fill_between(x_2, y_m - 100 * y_v / 2, y_m + 100 * y_v / 2, color="blue")
plt.plot(x_2, y_m, color="red")
```

resulting:

now this implementation has two major drawbacks which are the fact that it assumes the x data are evenly distributed and sorted, which is not necessarily always the case.